# alarm manger does not work at the specified time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I create an activity for settings and in it I create a switch to send notifications at a specific time at 7 am and 5 pm. When I checked the switch, two notifications appeared.

The code of switch is

```
public void OnRepeationNotification(int id,int hours,int minutes,int seconds) {
    Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hours);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,seconds);
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}

public void onClickNotify(View view) {
    Switch v=(Switch) view;
    if(v.isChecked()){
        putSett(true,"sett",this,0);
        OnRepeationNotification(1,7,0,0);
        OnRepeationNotification(2,17,0,0);

    }else {
        alert_sound.setChecked(false);
        alert_vibrate.setChecked(false);
        putSett(false,"sett",this,1);
        putSett(false,"sett",this,2);
        putSett(false,"sett",this,0);
    }
}
```

the code of Broadcast receiver

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendNotification(context,1);
        sendNotification(context,2);
    }

    public void sendNotification(Context context,int id){
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent=new Intent(context,RepeatingActivity.class);

        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent  pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fav_black)
                .setContentTitle("Notifiction Title")
                .setContentText("Notification Text")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());
    }
}
```

How to send notifications even when the app is closed or the device is rebooted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notifications will fire immediately if the time they are set for has already passed on the current day.  To fix this, you need to check if the time has already passed, and if it has then add this to the calendar object to set the alarms for the following day:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

The alarms will stay active if the user closes the app by swiping it away in the 'recent apps' screen.  In order to keep the alarms alive after a phone reboot, you will need to make a `BroadcastReceiver` with the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent filter in its manifest declaration, like this:

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Inside of that `BroadcastReceiver`, you should run an `IntentService` which then restarts all of your alarms.

Comment: the two notifications still appear together regardless i set different time

Comment: They both appear right when you flip the switch?  Did you add the `calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);` part?

Comment: I set this code Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(calendar.before(rightNow));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1); is that right

Comment: Yes and they are still firing right away?  Try adding `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` right after both Calendars are instantiated.  Then run it and in the terminal, do `adb shell dumpsys alarm` and search your package name to see when the alarms are set for